# unification of two quadratic equations with two variables

Tags: quadratics

I have two quadratic equations with two variables like below:

$f(x,y)=18xy+5x+19y+5$

$f(x,y)=18xy+11x+7y+4 $

Is there a way to unite the two equations? Are there any SW tools that could render the two equations and as output yield a third equation that could present an estimate of the two equations united?

Comment: they are not quadratic

Comment: Are you looking for a parametric equation describing intersection between these two surfaces?

Comment: @kajelad yes, that would be it. The intersection is where they both hold.